# Update parent field

Tags: apex, lookup, dml

I have an order which I am creating from another order and I have lookup on order - ParentOrder__c. When I create the child order, I would like to update field Prolongated__c(which is checkbox) on parent order. Is it possible to do without SOQL query? I am trying to set newOrder.ParentOrder__r.Prolongated__c = true, but it returns NullPointer exception to me. But when I try to debug newOrder.ParentOrder__r.Prolongated__c it seems to be ok. Why isn't it the right way to update parent order and what's the right one without querying it? Code is below. Thanks!

```
public static Id prolongateTestOrder(Id orderId, Decimal duration) {
    Order newOrder = cloneOrderForProlongation(orderId, duration);
    List<Order> ordersList = new List<Order>{newOrder};
    
    DMLProcessor.insertRecords(ordersList, true, true);

    System.debug('newOrder.ParentOrder__c = ' + newOrder.ParentOrder__c);
    System.debug('newOrder.ParentOrder__r.Prolongated__c = ' + newOrder.ParentOrder__r.Prolongated__c);
    newOrder.ParentOrder__r.Prolongated__c = true;

    if (newOrder.IsStandardConfiguration__c == false) {
        List<OrderItem> newOrderItems = cloneOrderItemsForProlongate(orderId, newOrder.Id);
        DMLProcessor.insertRecords(newOrderItems, true, true);
    }

    newOrder.Status = OrderHelper.ORDER_STATUS_NAME_IN_APPROVAL;
    DMLProcessor.updateRecords(ordersList, true, true);

    createEvents(ordersList, PLATFORM_EVENT_TYPE_TEST_ORDER_PROLONGATED);

    return newOrder.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All we really need to be able to update a record is the Id of that record. If `orderId` is the Id of the parent order, then you can create a new instance of that record, set your desired field, then update it.

e.g.

```
Order parentOrder = new Order(
    Id = orderId,
    Prolongated__c = true
);

update parentOrder;
```

#### As for why your current code doesn't work...

Every field on an SObject in Salesforce needs to either be queried for, or explicitly set by you somewhere in code. Records in trigger context variables are the main exception to that, but in a trigger context variable you'll only get the fields directly on the object your trigger is for.

If you have to use more than one dot/period/full-stop to access a field (as you are when you try to execute `newOrder.ParentOrder__r.Prolongated__c = true;`), then you need to have either queried for `ParentOrder__r.<any field>` or have first set `newOrder.ParentOrder__r`.

`newOrder.ParentOrder__c` holds the related record Id, and `newOrder.ParentOrder__r` holds an instance of the related SObject. It's an SObject embedded inside of another SObject, and in most cases you can simply do something like `newOrder.ParentOrder__r = new Order();`

Even if you did that though, updating `newOrder` would not cause any changes you made to the parent order to be saved as well (dml only operates on the base record).

#### As for why your debug statements didn't throw a Null Pointer Exception.

That's just Salesforce being nice. We have the safe navigation operator (`?.`) now, but before we had that, Salesforce was basically doing something similar for us behind the scenes when navigating through SObjects on the RHS (right hand side) of an expression.

That allows us to do things like `System.debug('newOrder.ParentOrder__r.Prolongated__c = ' + newOrder.ParentOrder__r.Prolongated__c);` without adding explicit null checks. I don't believe we know the exact mechanism here, but I'd be willing to bet that Salesforce is stopping the evaluation of `newOrder.ParentOrder__r.Prolongated__c` after the `ParentOrder__r` bit is evaluated (it returns null, so anything after that can be ignored, kinda like short-circuit evaluation for boolean statements).